# COPY failed in git actions

Tags: docker, github-actions

Dockerfile :

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} backend.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/backend.jar"]
```

deploy.yml:

```
jobs:
  push_to_registry:
    name: Push Docker image to Docker Hub
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out the repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Push to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v1
        with:
          path: backend
          dockerfile: backend/Dockerfile
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          repository: myname/myrepo
          tag_with_ref: true
```

Github actions result:

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for openjdk:11-jdk-slim
 ---> b4517d9514cb
Step 2/4 : ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
 ---> Running in 640e9a32e282
Removing intermediate container 640e9a32e282
 ---> e9414330bf73
Step 3/4 : COPY ${JAR_FILE} backend.jar
COPY failed: no source files were specified
exit status 1
Error: exit status 1
```

I don't know why it says that source files were not specified, I have a other workflow, where I do exactly the same, but without build-push-action module, and it works fine.

Comment: Maybe there isn't anything in `target/` that ends in `.jar`?

Comment: @tadman your comment is obvious, but sometimes we forget about obvious things... I forgot to make a step to compile the maven repository... 3 hours well spent! Thank you, though!

Comment: Happy to be another pair of eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Forgot to put a compile step before build:

```
      - name: Maven Package
        run: mvn -B clean compile package -DskipTests
```